# Run test files sequentially?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have multiple test files. Each file has a `before` and `after` functions, doing server startup,shutdown and db cleaning activities.

Structure of a sample test file:

```
describe('some test:', function() {

    before('reset db; start server', start_server)
    after('close server', close_server)

    // some tests
    describe('#clear_expired_signals:', clear_expired_signals)
    describe('#delete_signal ', delete_signal)
}
```

I am getting `EADDRINUSE` exception most of the times when these files are executed together because the server is being started in the same port during each `before` call.

Is it possible to force mochajs to execute single file at a time ( **file order is not a concern**) ?

Edit:

> before function sample

```
  function start_server(done) {   
    intialize_server.start().then(function(options) {

     seneca = options.seneca;
     seneca.client({
       host: 'localhost',
       port:options.port,
     }); 
     done();
  }

}



function intialize_server(){
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    seneca.ready(function () {

      seneca.listen({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: custom_port,
      });

      resolve({
        seneca: seneca,
        port: custom_port
      });
      // console.log('test server listening')
    });
  });
 }
```

> after function sample

```
 function close_server(done) {
   console.log('closing seneca instance');
  seneca.close(done);
  }
```

Comment: Is any of your code (before, after, tests themselves) asynchronous?

Comment: Did you have done passed in `it` function?

Comment: Try passing a `done` callback to your `after` to allow mocha to wait for server to close before running the next test.

Comment: @Bergi yes. I am cleaning some folder and starting server , which is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around this problem. Instead of running `before` and `after` for each test file, I have added `ROOT-LEVEL HOOKS` as given in the documentation

> **ROOT-LEVEL HOOKS**
>
> You may also pick any file and add “root”-level hooks. For example,
>   add beforeEach() outside of all describe() blocks. This will cause the
>   callback to beforeEach() to run before any test case, regardless of
>   the file it lives in (this is because Mocha has an implied describe()
>   block, called the “root suite”).